# query every single database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to search every database in my DB search (they all have the same table name) with the following:

`SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM TABLE WHERE NAME  = 'blah'`

I have tried this:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
      [COUNT] INT
    , DB VARCHAR(50)
)

DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(50) 
SELECT @TableName = '[dbo].[TABLE]'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
    SELECT CHAR(13) + 'SELECT ''' + name + ''', COUNT(1) FROM [' + name + '].' + @TableName
    FROM sys.databases 
    WHERE OBJECT_ID(name + '.' + @TableName) IS NOT NULL
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

INSERT INTO #temp (DB, [COUNT])              
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

SELECT * 
FROM #temp t
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use (the undocumented) [`sp_msforeachdb`](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx). It's usage is:

```
exec sp_msforeachdb @command1 = N'insert into #tmp select "?", * from [?].dbo.table';
```

Of note is the `?`, which is a placeholder for the database name. Within the `@command1` string, double-quotes are used in place of single-quotes.

This procedure will also enumerate the system databases, and you can fairly easily sidestep that by appending `if db_id("?") > 4` to skip them.